# Date histogram exact match

Tags: elasticsearch

Histogram aggregation rounds every result to closest bucket within the interval:

> If the documents have a field that holds a price (numeric), we can configure this aggregation to dynamically build buckets with interval 5 (in case of price it may represent $5). When the aggregation executes, **the price field of every document will be evaluated and will be rounded down to its closest bucket** - for example, if the price is 32 and the bucket size is 5 then the rounding will yield 30 and thus the document will "fall" into the bucket that is associated with the key 30

I need to aggregate documents using date histogram without this rounding, so only documents with date strictly equals bucket key will fall into the bucket.

For example:

```
{"date": "2016-01-10"}
{"date": "2016-01-11"}
{"date": "2016-01-13"}
{"date": "2016-01-14"}

{
"aggs" : {
    "strict" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
            "field" : "date",
            "interval" : "2d"
        }
    }
}}
```

Expected result:

```
{
"aggregations": {
    "strict": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key_as_string": "2016-01-10",
                "key": ...,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2016-01-12",
                "key": ...,
                "doc_count": 0
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2016-01-14",
                "key": ...,
                "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

Comment: Then use `day` interval. If you use `2d` it's evident that the odd days will fall into even day buckets. If you specifically need to disregard odd days, then you can apply a filter to dismiss documents with odd dates.

Comment: @Val my example is quite simple, just to show the idea that each bucket must contain only documents with date that strictly equals to the bucket key. The inverval may be any, not just 2 days.

Comment: Then I don't think that `date_histogram` is made for that.